# How to remove line separators from JTextArea in SeaGlass L&F?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, look-and-feel, seaglass

I am using line separators in the SeaGlass L&F and had recently noticed that in my `JTextArea`, there are line separators between the lines.

[image: Screenshot]

How to remove line separators from `JTextArea` in SeaGlass L&F?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is controlled by a system property `SeaGlass.JTextArea.drawLineSeparator`. Try setting it to `false`:

```
System.setProperty("SeaGlass.JTextArea.drawLineSeparator", "false");
```

I found it in [TextComponentPainter](https://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/xref/com/seaglasslookandfeel/painter/TextComponentPainter.html) source.